# Using parameters with a database connection class

Tags: c#, sql, class, parameters

I am trying to add Sql Parameters to my project but i have the database connections in a class. How would i go about adding them as the code is trying to read employerId as a column name

I have this code in a class to read and return from a database:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteQuery(String query)        
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,sqlConn);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                
    return reader;
}
```

and this code in a web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string CheckTime1(string employerId)
{
    try
    {
        UseDatabase useDb = new UseDatabase("database.mdf");
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [employer] WHERE [employerId] =" + employerId;
        useDb.ConnectToDatabase();

        SqlDataReader dbReader = useDb.ExecuteQuery(queryString);
        if (dbReader != null && dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            return "RECORDS EXIST";
        }
        else if (dbReader == null)
        {
            return "RECORDS DONT EXIST";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error";
        }    
        useDb.DisconectDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception exq)
    {
        return exq.ToString(); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be me, but could you clarify your problem a bit please?

Comment: Not an answer, but an advice, these approaches using a 'make-it-all' database classes are usually more a pain than a gain. The class is often incomplete and the tradeoff required to lower the complexity have a direct impact on performance or in security. I suggest to invest some of your time to use a ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) that has been tested and it is well know for its speed instead of trying to fix your database class.

Comment: In order to use `SqlParameter` you need a `SqlCommand`. Looks like you've wrapped `SqlConnection` in your `UseDatabase` class? Does that support running `SqlCommand`?

Answer (score 0):

Although I strongly encourage you to rethink your data access layer from scratch, here is an easy solution to your problem:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteQuery(String query, params object[] p)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p"+i, p[i]));
    }

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return reader;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
public string CheckTime1(string employerId)
{
        ...

        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [employer] WHERE [employerId] = @p0";

        SqlDataReader dbReader = useDb.ExecuteQuery(queryString, employerId);

        ...
}
```

Comment: Why `params object[]` and not just an `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>`? You're also assuming that the OP can modify the `UseDatabase` class. OP hasn't stated who the owner of that class is, so it may not be an option. All speculation of course because the question lacks so much essential information.

Comment: True, OP didn't state who owns the `UseDatabase` class. And yes, you can pass either SqlParameters directly or Dictionary<string,object> to construct the parameters. But using implicitly named parameters just seems as the easiest solution here. Kind of fits the overall design. Don't get me wrong, I'm not recommending this as state of the art DAL, I'm merely saying this answers the question.